# Big O of an infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Consider the following code:

```
int value = 0;

while(getRandomNumber() != 1000) {
    value++;
}

return value;
```

What would be the Big O (worst case, best case and average case) of the above code?

Comment: Depends *highly*  on `some_statment`.

Comment: if some_statement can't/won't change in the loop, then yes, the whole thing is O(infinite)

Comment: Adding randomization to algorithms change their analysis from deterministic approaches to expected approaches. Gave more details in an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question here does not make a lot of sense. First of all big O notation depends on the input, here there is no input to your algorithm at all.

The time of the execution here depends on the set of possible values of your `getRandomNumber` and on its underlying distribution.

For example if your RNG returns numbers from `[1 to 100]` - the algorithm will never finish. On the other hand if it generates only `1000` and `1001` with equal probability, on average it will take 2 iterations to finish. The worse case would be infinity, but it does not make any sense at all because it is so unlikely.

Comment: Since it doesn't depend on the size of the input n, does this mean an infinite loop is constant and O(1)?

Comment: @AlSweigart by the definition infinite loop depends on the size of n and no matter how big n is the loop takes more than O(n), O(n^2), O(n!), O(n^n)

Answer (score 8):

When speaking about complexity, `n` is the size of the input in bits. Here, there is **no** input. So `n` is fixed and equals to `0`. So technically there is no complexity because there cannot be any variation in the input size.

You can however ask the questions: how many times will the loop execute on average, maximally or minimally...

Comment: Thanks. If I ask how many times will the loop execute maximally will it be O(∞)?

Comment: It really depends on your random generator :) It may be infinite if it doesn't generate 1000, or it can be a single iteration if it always return 1000... https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @user2726225 You plug it into the formula `E[iterations] = (1 - p) / p` where `p = 1 / numberOfPossibleOutcomes`

Answer (score 1):

1. The worst case is `O(∞)`, the best case is `0(1)`.
2. Yes, but every algorithm has complexity `O(∞)`, thus it isn't very useful information.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the *expected* time complexity. In your particular case, this is the expected value (mean) of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Expected_number_of_failures_before_the_first_success).

For instance, the expected number of iterations for your loop is given by:

```
E[iterations] = (1 - p) / p
```

where `p` is the probability of getting exactly 1000.

```
p = P(X=1000)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a birthday problem

Comment: @SalvadorDali Yes, I confused it with hash collisions. Which probably makes no sense, but I've only had 6 hours of sleep/day for the past week...

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

Others have pointed out good information, but failed to address something very important. As soon as you introduce randomization, you want to look at expected time, not deterministic analysis. To answer your questions:

- **Best case:** `Ω(1)`
- **Worse Case:** `O(∞)`
- **Average Case:** See expected analysis below.

**Note on Best Case**

Notice for best case that it is big omega, not big O (https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation)

**Expected Analysis**

As soon as you introduce randomization, you are no longer get to rely on deterministic analysis. Instead you start to deal with "expected analysis". As Mateen points out, your instance can be solved with a geometric distribution. Since I don't know the range of values your get random number function can return (nor the distribution of numbers), we can't answer your question directly. Mateen's analysis looks good, as he doesn't assume your probability of getting 1000.

**Side Notes**

For other types of random problems, you can use other tools, such as Marchov Chains (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). I've seen tools like these used in analysis of Randomized Online Algorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adversary_model), if this is of interest to you, then the links should provide you with a wealth of other links to read.

The introduction of randomization adds a new level of fun to algorithm analysis. Hope this helps, and have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

If `some_statement` is and remains false for the whole duration of the loop then, yes, the loop is infinite and has O(Infinity) complexity.
However the loop becomes finite once `some_statement` becomes true. It can even be O(1) - constant if `some_statement` is true at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code. Now the if statement depends on a random number which is decided inside the loop and the execution of the return statement is unpredictable. What would be the result now?

Comment: What kind of random number? What are the chances for it to be true/false? Do you need worst-case complexity or average-case?

Comment: Lets say the random number is unpredictable. So the condition can be true any time but there is a possibility for the condition to never be true. I need the worst case complexity. I don't think it is possible to have an average case but would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: Worst case would be that the condition never gets true, so your loop is indeed infinite i.e. O(infinity). And you're right, without precise numbers about the chances of the statement being true, you can't really have an average case.